# Multiple users edit a single question and get +2 reputation each is it generic?

Tags: discussion

Bad formatted question edited by multiple user and each user get +2 reputation is it generic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by "generic"; I'll assume you mean "intentional".

Yes, it's intentional that any user who is eligible to earn the +2 points for editing, receives that +2 points when an edit they suggest to a question or answer is approved.

The number of people who have already edited it is irrelevant.

Comment: Each individual user edit also get +2 points.Just an example if two users edit the same thing then they also get +2 points each.

Comment: If they're eligible for those points, yes. That's by design, otherwise only the first person to edit a post would get +2 points, which isn't what we're going for.

Comment: Thank @Clive clear my doubt.